# Is it possible to control CPU resources sharing among VBoxHeadless virtual machines?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

If I run 3 VirtualBox machines on a physical server and eventually start a tough data processing on one of them, are there means to make sure the remaining 2 ones are not suppressed? Can I guarantee some minimum resources to a virtual machine and give all the unused resources (as a background priority) to a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to approach it, yes - there are several ways. Unfortunately I am not aware of a simple "*use no more than 80% of the total CPU resources available even though I allocated all of them to each of the three machines*".

Here are three approaches:

Assuming you have a quad-core server, simply allocate [one or two virtual processors](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-processor) to each VM. This will ensure that no VM can ever exceed more than 50% of the host CPU capacity.

You could also try using a program like [cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/)  if your host operating system supports it. Virtualization these days goes beyond just a simple process so your mileage may vary but it seems to work well.

A slightly more interesting scenario is to use the [CPU Hot-Plugging](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#cpuhotplug) feature of VirtualBox. Unfortunately there is somewhat limited support for it in the various guest operating systems. You could use this to scale up/down dynamically if your environment supports it.

Here is a screenshot for the VM settings showing where the virtual CPU count can be configured:

[image]

Comment: "Assuming you have a quad-core server, simply allocate one or two virtual processors to each VM." - simple and obviously-looking as every genius idea! I'll try reading the manual to find how to actually do so.